# Dealing with Excel formula length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Following a successful DB/app development I've been tasked with creating a pretty advanced spreadsheet for use by our recruitment team.

Long story short, there's a formula to work out the "required staff" versus "attendees" at a camp.

The attendance and staff data is being pulled two other worksheets via an ODBC connection, and being turned into pretty pivot tables.

There is a fairly easy to understand, but ultimately quite programatically complex calculation to be done. This takes about 8 steps.

Given that [to my knowledge] you can't make short term variables within a cell, and combined with the fact to reference an external cell takes quite a of of chars, I've ended up with a visually (if not conceptually) complex formula.

Ultimately... as I've added some data validation using IFERROR() to tackle the uncertainty of the data, it means I've actually hit the character limit of a cell (about 8100 chars). I tried FSVO minifying the cell, and that hasn't got me back below the limit.

So - now you know the issue - Here's the set of questions:

- Is there a way of extending the limit?
- Is there a way of making variables inside a cell (which would also solve the problem)?
- Is VB suitable for this kind of problem?

I suspect that the answer is going to be: "go and learn some VB"... which I was trying to avoid. I reckon I'm about 3 lines off the limit, and given that it's a tried and tested solution, it's shame to have to recode it.

EDITED TO INCLUDE THE FORMULA

```
=IF(
    OR(
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),

        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),

        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
        IFERROR(
        GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)
    ),

 SUM(
        IF(
            OR(
                IFERROR(
                GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
                IFERROR(
                GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
                IFERROR(
                GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)
            ),
                SUM(
                    (
                    (IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)+($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49)))/$B$49
                    )
                    +
                    (
                    ((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49)))+($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$50
                    )
                    +
                    (
                    CEILING(
                        IF(
                            ((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$51)<0,
                            0,
                            (
                            (IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","Multi-Active","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$51
                            )
                        ),1
                    )
                    )
                )
                ,
                0
        )
        +

        IF(
            OR(
                IFERROR(
                GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
                IFERROR(
                GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),
                IFERROR(
                GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)
            ),      
            SUM(
                (
                (IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)+($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49)))/$B$49
                )
                +
                (
                ((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49)))+($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$50
                )
                +
                (
                    CEILING(
                    IF(
                    ((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$51)<0,
                    0,
                    (
                    (IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","ISS","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$51
                    )
                    ),1
                    )
                )
            )
            ,
            0
        )       
        +
        SUM(
                (
                (IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)+($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49)))/$B$49
                )
                +
                (
                ((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49)))+($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$50
                )
                +
                (
                CEILING(
                        IF(
                         ((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$51)<0,
                         0,
                         (
                         (IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","8 + years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$50-(MOD((IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","6/7 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0)-($B$49-MOD(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Child ID",'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1,"Venue",$A4,"Age group","4/5 years","Activity","MVC","date",B$1-DATE(YEAR(B$1),1,0)),0),$B$49))),$B$50))))/$B$51
                         )
                        ),1
                    )
                )
        )       
 ),

 "-"
)
```

Comment: Can you not store intermediate results in cells?

Comment: Nope - there are about 300*40 cells, all referencing up to 12 different "intermediate stages". Visual layout requirements dictate that these are in a grid with no other intermediate cells between them.

Comment: Can we see the formula?

Comment: Formula added. This is minified in the real cells.

Comment: You need to factor out the common code into separate cells (on a new sheet if necessary) or use defined names (yes, you can indeed put a formula in a defined name).

Comment: TO recap what I said: the reason this is so long is that I cannot use separate cells [due to layout requirements]. 
Unfortunately this is going to have to be a one cell approach.

Comment: Wow, thats a lot of formula! You might be able to shave some characters off by using named ranges instead of direct cell addresses. All your `'Child Numbers 2013'!$A$1` become `SOMETHINGSMALLER`

Comment: Your layout requirements will not be impacted if you put intermediate results in a new sheet or in defined names.

Comment: Ironically - it's only about 10 lines before you add the error catching and external references...

Thanks - with that suggestion, I have two approaches atm:
Going to try to move some of the "iferrors()" back a level, I'll try the named ranges too.

Comment: @RickMorice, are you familiar with 'hiding' columns and tabs from view? You can store your intermediate values in a hidden tab and reference it in your visible tab. Just right-click on the tab names to hide/unhide.

Comment: Defined names has cracked it. FYI all - I've redefined the reference to the external pivot table to be CN, and that's saved hundreds of chars.

Answer (score 0):

Defined names has cracked it. FYI all - I've redefined the reference to the external pivot table to be CN as opposed to the full name, and that's saved hundreds of chars. 
Thanks all! I've marked up all who suggested this.